# GWT Mobile web app development UI module

Tags: gwt, mobile

As a GWT developer, I'm looking to expand my GWT development skills to Mobile web app development using HTML5. I could understand, by default, GWT web application works well with mobile browsera and HTML5 features have already been added into GWT SDK. However, I am looking for  a good GWT project or module which I could add into my GWT project to get native look on mobile web application. I feel, JQuery mobile or Sencha touch provide styles to get native look in this case.

Is there anything else other than https://github.com/dennisjzh/GwtMobile-UI?

Is  there any active GWT - UI development project going on for mobile application to get native look? Or, Should I seriously consider to use JQuery mobile than GWT for mobile web application development?

Comment: For example there is [m-gwt](http://m-gwt.com/) framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.m-gwt.com and code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/

I would also recommend watching the GWT Roadmap talk from this year's Google I/O.  Really cool stuff being done with GWT and mobile.  https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327833110